# ICMP outbound to Internet with Azure Firewall

Tags: azure

I have a rule in Azure Firewall that basically should allow ICMP to any destination.

```
    {
        description: 'Allow Ping to Any'
        name: 'rule-allow-ping'
        ruleType: 'NetworkRule'
        destinationAddresses: [
          '*'
        ]
        destinationPorts: [
          '*'
        ]
        ipProtocols: [
          'ICMP'
        ]
        sourceIpGroups: [
          ipVMs.id
        ]
      }
```

When I ping internally (between 2 peered VNETs), it works fine.

When I ping externally (for example 8.8.8.8), I get no reply.

Is there an additional setting to enable or is it a "normal" behavior (documented somewhere)?

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/archive/blogs/mast/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity

> Because the ICMP protocol is not permitted through the Azure load balancer, you will notice that you are unable to ping an Azure VM from the internet, and from within the Azure VM, you are unable to ping internet locations.

However if you were to give the VM a Public IP you can ping it from the internet, as long as you create a Network Security Group rule and rule in Azure Firewall to allow it inbound.

Even with a public IP however letting the VM ping the internet outbound is not possible:

> Also note that while an instance-level public IP lets you communicate directly to a specific VM instead of through the cloud service VIP that can be used for multiple VMs, ICMP is not permitted in that scenario either.

And as far as I know this also applies to any VM behind Azure Firewall.